# Swift cant animate view.origin.y

Tags: ios, swift

I am moving my view up when the keyboard appears in order to not cover the input field.

I am doing this by the following code:

```
var keyboardShown: Bool = false {
        didSet(oldValue) {
            let keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 216
            var frame = view.frame
            if keyboardShown {
                frame.origin.y = -keyboardHeight
            } else {
                frame.origin.y = 0
            }
            view.frame = frame
        }
    }


    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        keyboardShown = true
    }
```

This works but there is no animation so it looks odd with the view just jumping up. So is there a function in order to animate this?

Also, do I need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try this

Add these notification for keyboard in viewDidLoad

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

And do whatever with these methods when keyboard show or hide

```
func keyboardWillShow(note: NSNotification) {
    var userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = note.userInfo
    var duration: NSTimeInterval = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey].doubleValue()
    var curve: UIViewAnimationCurve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey].integerValue()
    var keyboardFrameEnd: CGRect = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey].CGRectValue()
    keyboardFrameEnd = self.view.convertRect(keyboardFrameEnd, fromView: nil)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | curve, animations: {        self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, keyboardFrameEnd.size.width, keyboardFrameEnd.origin.y)

    }, completion: nil)
}

func keyboardWillHide(note: NSNotification) {
    var userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = note.userInfo
    var duration: NSTimeInterval = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey].doubleValue()
    var curve: UIViewAnimationCurve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey].integerValue()
    var keyboardFrameEnd: CGRect = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey].CGRectValue()
    keyboardFrameEnd = self.view.convertRect(keyboardFrameEnd, fromView: nil)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | curve, animations: {        self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, keyboardFrameEnd.size.width, keyboardFrameEnd.origin.y)

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Enjoy :)